# Atmosphere 'socket' not getting reference

Tags: jquery, atmosphere

Hi I am trying to create a simple Chat application using Atmosphere. 
My Application1.xml is not able to create a reference of "Socket" using 
`var socket = $.atmosphere;`.

Below are the codeblocks I have used. I'm a noob in atmosphere.

**application1.xml**
    $(function () {
    "use strict";

```
var content = $('#content');
var input = $('#input');
var status = $('#status');
var myName = false;
var author = null;
var logged = false;
var socket = $.atmosphere;
var request = { url: document.location.toString() + 'chat',
                contentType : "application/json",
                logLevel : 'debug',
                transport : 'websocket' ,
                trackMessageLength : true,
                fallbackTransport: 'long-polling'};


request.onOpen = function(response) {
    content.html($('<p>', { text: 'Atmosphere connected using ' + response.transport }));
    input.removeAttr('disabled').focus();
    status.text('Choose name:');
};

request.onMessage = function (response) {
    var message = response.responseBody;
    try {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(message);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('This doesn\'t look like a valid JSON: ', message);
        return;
    }

    input.removeAttr('disabled').focus();
    if (!logged) {
        logged = true;
        status.text(myName + ': ').css('color', 'blue');
    } else {
        var me = json.author == author;
        var date =  jQuery.now();
        addMessage(json.author, json.message, me ? 'blue' : 'black', new Date(date));
    }
};

request.onClose = function(response) {
    logged = false;
}

request.onError = function(response) {
    content.html($('<p>', { text: 'Sorry, but there\'s some problem with your '
        + 'socket or the server is down' }));
};

var subSocket = socket.subscribe(request);

input.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();

        // First message is always the author's name
        if (author == null) {
            author = msg;
        }

        subSocket.push(jQuery.stringifyJSON({ author: author, message: msg }));
        $(this).val('');

        input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if (myName === false) {
            myName = msg;
        }
    }
});

function addMessage(author, message, color, datetime) {
    content.append('<p><span style="color:' + color + '">' + author + '</span> @ ' +
        + (datetime.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + datetime.getHours() : datetime.getHours()) + ':'
        + (datetime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + datetime.getMinutes() : datetime.getMinutes())
        + ': ' + message + '</p>');
}
```

});

**atmosphere.js**

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to declare atmosphere variable like this :

```
var socket = $.atmosphere;
```

If atmosphere library is declared into your bower.json and all javascript sources from atmosphere into bower components, assign the variable atmosphere like :

```
var socket = atmosphere;
```